# Corine data aspect analysis in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, zonal-statistics, aspect

I have a SRTM dataset, Corine Land Cover and have already calculated aspect.

I want to know the relative proportions of exposition classes of certain landcover type.

My thought was to use zonal statistics, but I always get an error. I have tried to convert the aspect raster (floating point) to an integer already, but that seems to be not the right direction.

Anyone with an idea to get a solution?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It's just the "Error 999999: Error executing function". My idea was I'm using maybe the wrong data, but not sure

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to run the **Reclass** Tool on the Aspect information. Reclassing will redefine the Aspect data into classes.

You can decide the classes, perhaps look at defining it into a Cardinal Direction? N,NE,E..etc.

You can then convert this reclassed aspect dataset into a Polygon, using the Polygon to Raster Tool.

Convert the Landuse into Polygon as well.

Take these two data sets (now Polygons) and run an Intersect. This will give you the Landcover associated with a specific Aspect.

You can then analyse this information as you need to for your application.

Comment: a lot of calculation needed, but it has worked. Many thanks!